# How does 1 address line give you 2 bytes of data?

Tags: cpu-architecture, cpu-word, processor

In the quora answer: https://www.quora.com/How-many-number-of-address-lines-is-needed-for-processor-to-access-4MB-memory - the top answer starts with 1 address line giving you 2 bytes of data. But my question is how mathematically?

Comment: A 1-bit binary signal: 2^1 = 2, assuming byte addressable memory and an access size of only 1 byte.  Are you maybe mixing up an address line with a "data request" signal to ask the memory to do anything at all?  You do need other control signals, not *just* an address line.

Answer (score 1):

A single address line can be in one of two states - either in state 0 or 1, hence it is able to address two distinct locations.